# How to check a BCH(15,11,1) code/checksum for BDS/Beidou satellite system

Tags: c, algorithm, checksum, parity

In the PDF http://www.beidou.gov.cn/attach/2012/12/27/201212273da29c5eb8274deb8cd2b178228ba2bd.pdf chapter 5 (pages 9ff) the BCH(15,11,1) code for Beidou system is described.

I'm trying to implement usage of this code for error checking (i.e. I only want to verify the parity information - I don't need the error fixing capability). Ideally I search a routine, which gets 15 bits and returns the matching 4 parity bits.

I checked the following code, but couldn't get it to do what I want. In best it makes a BCH(15,11,3) code.

http://www.eccpage.com/bch3.c

Two example strings are:
E240DCB12D8201A043FFA7277777BA7777777B777776A777803503C00133E000EEC6EEEEEE60
E2411C9D2D9DD17DDDDDDA9DDDE0D500F0026478001635555552D555554B5555552D555554B0

Note that first 15 bits aren't BCH-encoded, second set is, and beginning with 3rd set two encodings are interleaved, as described on page 14.

I.E. the first BCH(15,11,1) set should be 01101110010 1100, the second without interleave
0100101101100000100000 00011010 and splitted
01001011011 0001 and 00000100000 1010.

What I'm searching is a routine, which gets these 11+4 bits and can verify the parity. Interleaving handling and all other stuff I can do myself. As said, error correction is not important for me, I only need a yes/no.

Anything which would help me is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging deeper into the topic I found a working solution. I'll give it here as reference for anybody who has the same problem.

NOTE: GETBITS is a macros, which extracts given number of bits from the "data" variable and stores them into the supplied argument. I'm to lazy to extract and reduce the relevant code, so use your own version :-)

```
static int checkbds(int bits)
{
  static int const at[15] = {1, 2, 4, 8, 3, 6, 12, 11, 5, 10, 7, 14, 15, 13, 9};
  int s, i, j;

  for(i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
  {
    s = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
      if(bits & (1<<j))
      {
        s ^= at[(i * j) % 15];
      }
    }
    if(s != 0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

int bdsbch(const unsigned char *data)
{
  int 38, i, b, b2, j;

  GETBITS(b, 15) /* drop first 15 bits */

  GETBITS(b, 15) /* get first bit set */
  if(!checkbds(b))
    return 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
  {
    GETBITS(b, 11) /* get first bit set */
    GETBITS(b2, 11) /* get second bit set */
    GETBITS(j, 4)
    b = (b<<4)|j;
    GETBITS(j, 4)
    b2 = (b2<<4)|j;
    if(!checkbds(b) || !checkbds(b2))
      return 0;
  }
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%d\n", bdsbch((const unsigned char*)"\xE2\x40\xDC\xB1\x2D\x82\x01\xA0\x43\xFF"
                  "\xA7\x27\x77\x77\xBA\x77\x77\x77\x7B\x77\x77\x76\xA7\x77\x80"
                  "\x35\x03\xC0\x01\x33\xE0\x00\xEE\xC6\xEE\xEE\xEE\x60"));
  printf("%d\n", bdsbch((const unsigned char*)"\xE2\x41\x1C\x9D\x2D\x9D\xD1\x7D\xDD\xDD"
                  "\xDA\x9D\xDD\xE0\xD5\x00\xF0\x02\x64\x78\x00\x16\x35\x55\x55"
                  "\x52\xD5\x55\x55\x4B\x55\x55\x55\x2D\x55\x55\x54\xB0"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no interleaving implemented in your code. But ICD BEIDOU tells that there is. Your code is properly working ?

By the way my crc calculation function is

```
typedef union {
    uint8_t val;
    struct {
        uint8_t b0:1;
        uint8_t b1:1;
        uint8_t b2:1;
        uint8_t b3:1;
    } bits;
} bch_reg;

uint8_t crc_calc(uint16_t data)
{
    bch_reg reg;
    int8_t i;
    uint8_t gate1; // icd
    reg.val = 0;

    for (i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
        gate1 = reg.bits.b3^(data >> i & 1);
        reg.bits.b3 = reg.bits.b2;
        reg.bits.b2 = reg.bits.b1;
        reg.bits.b1 = reg.bits.b0^gate1;
        reg.bits.b0 = gate1;
    }

    return reg.val;
}
```

oh, and one more thing. I have tried to calc crc without decoding and it doesn't work. So You nead to interleave than decode and then calc and check crc

```
uint16_t decode_bch_bin(uint16_t enc)
{
    bch_reg reg;
    int8_t i;
    uint8_t bit;
    uint16_t const err[16] = {0, 1, 2, 16, 4, 256, 32, 1024, 8, 16384, 512, 128, 64, 
        8192, 2048, 4096}; 
    /* see Table 5.2 */
    reg.val = 0;
    /* BCH decoding (Fig 5-4) */
    for (i = 14; i >= 0; i--) {
        bit = reg.bits.b3;
        reg.bits.b3 = reg.bits.b2;
        reg.bits.b2 = reg.bits.b1;
        reg.bits.b1 = reg.bits.b0^bit;
        reg.bits.b0 = (enc >> i & 1)^bit;
    }

    /*error correction*/
    enc ^= err[reg.val];
    /*wipe off crc bits*/
    return enc;
}
```

P.S. I prefer uin16_t to int because there are 15 bits in 1 code sequence, but it will work wis int as well

Comment: It depends where you get the data from. The data I get comes from the raw data sets of the receivers and the interleaving is already removed there. If you are nearer to the original data, then you need to take care for interleaving.

Comment: I recevied data right from after phase lock loops in the hardware, so i have bit streams just as satellite sends. But in any case before checking crc you have to do dch decode. Crc function implement the relative scheme in ICD Beidou